# Favicon works on localhost but not on a server?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, netlify

I'm currently trying to figure out why my favicon isn't showing up. It works fine on my localhost but when I go to upload it to Netlify, it doesn't show up.

[My favicon](https://amazing-almeida-72e847.netlify.com/favicon.ico)

[My website](https://amazing-almeida-72e847.netlify.com/)

I am using React and then deploying it to a Netlify server. Not sure if that has something to do with it. Here's what I put in my index.html file in the public folder.

`<link rel=”icon” href=”%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico”>`

And like I've already mentioned, it does work and show up with my localhost:3000. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: It works to me.  This is your icon, right: https://amazing-almeida-72e847.netlify.com/favicon.ico

Comment: @user2752635 I know that works, which doesn't make sense. I trying to see if just being on the index works. Maybe it is a caching issue on my side.

Comment: Are you using webpack? Are you using the react-cli to create your projects or you create your own webpack and config files?

Comment: @JacoboTapia I don't think I'm using a webpack. Lol. Kind of new to React. Let me Google this. I used, `create-react-app`.

Comment: Its working for me. Must be your cache issue..

Comment: @Sreeram I have a new problem. Now, my site on mobile doesn't load correctly, and skips my animations. I'd test it, but I only have a Pixel 3.

Comment: This sounds like a new issue entirely.

Comment: @user2752635 Classic XY problem. It wasn't loading correctly because of a different unrelated issue. I Might end up deleting this post as it serves no one.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove these extra quotation marks: `<link rel="”icon”" href="”/favicon.ico”">`.

Comment: I've updated it to be `<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">`, but it's still not working. Maybe clear cache?

Comment: Clearing the cache is always a good idea. The favicon works for me now. Try a new incognito window to be sure that nothing gets loaded from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and as many suggested in the comments, the problem was indeed in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

As link to favicon.ico will be rendered as http://{your server}/favicon.ico
favicon.ico file must be in your server root directory.